# How can I move data from BigQuery to same database in BigQuery but different schema?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, pipeline, data-migration

I am trying to move the data from Financial Schema tables to Looker_Scratch Schema tables.

Comment: There is bigquery transfer job that you can create if its on a regular basis. OR use Create Table as Select .... statements.

Comment: If the purpose of your transfer is a database table. I have good experience in transferring tables using NAVICAT software. Using this software, you can easily transfer tables in a short time.

you can use this link for this purpose: https://help.navicat.com/hc/en-us/articles/217791738-Can-I-copy-a-table-collection-by-Drag-and-Drop-

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this:

1. Using the UI follow the instructions in the documentation for [copying a single source table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copying_a_single_source_table).
2. Utilize the table snapshot function as described here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-create
3. Create a view to in the scratch dataset that points to the original.

The benefit to the snapshot is that it would be that it stores less data on disc than a full copy, however in both scenarios one and two above the data would become stale unless you put some kind of scheduled query or process behind it to refresh.  The view method would allow you to have the data be up to date as of the execution, this could present permissions issues so you may also want to look into authorized views.